# vertx-web httpserver messy code when response a Chinese word

Tags: vert.x

I met an issue when I was learning **Vert.x-Web**, below code will return a messy code for Chinese words, any one can help?

```
    HttpServer server = vertx.createHttpServer();

    server.requestHandler(request -> {

      // This handler gets called for each request that arrives on the server
      HttpServerResponse response = request.response();
      response.putHeader("content-type", "text/plain charset='utf-8'");

      // Write to the response and end it
      response.end("Hello World!中文");
    });

    server.listen(8080);
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found the reason, I think actually vert.x support UTF-8 encoding, but we need to make sure all the html files and related files including css, js, and font files all match UTF-8 format while saving it. we can use notepad open the file and check if it is UTF-8 format, if not, use "Save As..." to save it as UTF-8 format.